# Can Reducer have multiple keys at a single time?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, mapper, reducers

Through mapper I have made multiple keys and then passed them to reducer to perform some functionality. Is there a way I can send multiple keys a time to the same reducer? Actually I need the values associated with the keys in single reducer at a time. Thanks in advance!

Comment: post some code,so that your could be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is just to partition multiple keys to the same reducer, then you just write a customised `Partitioner` and generate same int for the keys you want to partitioned together.

Since you would realize partitioning isn't enough, and you'd like to also have multi keys sends to your `reduce(K k, Iterator<V>)` at a time, you may also need to implement a comparator, make the multi keys compared equal, and set the comparator as `job.setGroupingComparatorClass(GourpingClass.class)`.

As a adapted example from `Hadoop: The definitive Guide P279`:

Your data is like this:

```
1990 35  A1 A2 A3 A4
1990 34  B1 B2 B3 B4
1990 34  C2 C2 C3 C4
1991 36  [other data here]
1991 35  [other data here]
```

If you want make year & degree as a combine key of map output, and only partitions keys of different years to different reducers, you would just implement `YearPartitioner` :

```
public static class YearPartitioner extends Partitioner<CombineKey, V> {
    int getPartition(CombineKey k, V value, int numPartitions) { 
         return k.getyear % numPartitions;
    }
}
```

And Set `YearPartitioner` as `job.setPartitionerClass(YearPartitoner.class)`, by doing these, your data of 1990 would all sent to the same reducer, and your customised `reduce()` would first called by `<1990,35>` as key, and `<<A1 A2 A3 A4>>` as value lists, and again called by `<1990, 34>` as key and `<<B1 B2 B3 B4>,<C2 C2 C3 C4>>` as value lists.

If you want go further and get `reduce` be called `<1990,x>` as key, `<<A1 A2 A3 A4>,<B1 B2 B3 B4>,<C2 C2 C3 C4>>` as value lists at once, implement a keyComparator & set it as the `GroupingComparatorClass`